# After Page refresh Model items lost C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a below code and the problem is when i add item first time,then i add Id to the Model.Again i click the same button to edit something my models Id is null.It lost i have already assigned Id value.

### My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BusinessOrderAdd", "BusinessOrder", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "bsCurrForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
}
```

### My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult BusinessOrderAdd(myDTO myorder)
{
    myorder.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    return Json(myorder, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

### GET Method

```
public ActionResult BusinessOrderAdd()
{
    try
    {
        myorder.Date = DateTime.Now;
        myorder.StartTime = DateTime.Today.Date.AddHours(12);
        //some properties here.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return PartialView("_AddOrEditBusinessOrder", myorder);
}
```

Comment: @Rafalon OP changed

Comment: Can you please write down your get method here?

Comment: @Vasioky added to the post.pls check

Comment: Sorry but you've removed the part on which am interested, do you set the id in myorder before sending it to view? Also is not clear to me how you select the order that should be edited? Usually, an edit method should have a input id parameter but if it is add method than it is fine to be null case you just create a new order that will have an id only after you store it in database

Comment: In your GET method, `myorder` seems to come out of nowhere, is it intended?